# Firebase Authentication "Token exchange per project" Limits mean

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#token_service_api_limits
Token Service API limits
Operation                   Limit
Token exchange per project  18,000 exchanges/minute

What does Token Exchange mean please?
Is this the number of times the token is refreshed?

Please give me document about Token Exchange

Answer (score 1):

Tokens are valid for an hour and there is no need to refresh within that hour. 18,000/min means 1 million active users within an hour.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-refresh-token